# Is there a commentary concordance?

Tags: torah-study, technology, commentaries

I gather that there are both printed as well as on-line concordances for Tanac"h where one could enter a word or phrase and a list of matches appears.

Is there such a thing like a Rash"i or other commentary concordance? Sometimes, I vaguely recall Rash"i said something unusual (for example, I once tried to manually locate where Rash"i says "I don't know") but I don't know where he said it. Ideally, I'd like something that can be used to find matches in both Tanac"h as well as Talmud. On-line source would be better than book form (it's faster - usually :)

Is there any such tool around?

Comment: Such a tool would have to be massive and very concise.

Comment: Specifically Biblical commentaries?

Comment: @Oliver The answer below is good. As stated in my question, Talmud or, for that matter, any other *sefarim* would be useful, as well. My main focus is Biblical and Talmud.

Comment: @DanF Aha. Although I'd point out that search engines such as the two suggested in the answer below aren't concordances. The most they can do is add a prefix or suffix, not different conjugations of the principle word. Unless, you're not looking for the Even-Shoshan type concordance. (Or are you?)

Comment: @Oliver I've heard of Even Shoshan. But, what does that do that the others don't?

Comment: @DanF It arranges principle words in alphabetic order and lists the different conjugations. For example, say you were looking for 'אמרתי' or 'ואמרה' or 'ואמרתם' (you get the point), you'd turn to the root 'אמר' and among the list of conjugations you'll find all the places 'אמרתי' is listed. This system is not a simple search engine.

Comment: @Oliver on the other hand a search can do some things that a concordance can't.  For instance multiple words with <= a specified distance between them.  It's not often that you need the full power of Bar Ilan's tabular search, but when you do it's an incredibly useful tool to have.

Comment: @Heshy Sure there are advantages to a search engine but I didn't think OP needed them because of his asking about a concordance .

Comment: @Oliver I guess IO should edit my question, but, I thought that by stating "on line" I was implying search engines, as well. If you would, include your idea as an answer with a description of some of its features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/) has a search on the top left.  I haven't used it much, but as a test I searched for a relatively unusual word מערבבו which I know appears in a Rashi at the end of Vayeira.  Sure enough I got that Rashi, plus a Tzidkat Hatzadik and an Abudraham.

[Bar Ilan](https://www.responsa.co.il/default.aspx) also has a nice search feature.  While you can't browse without a subscription, the search is free.  (If you want the interface in English click the US flag in the top left.)  Their "tabular search", or "חיפוש טבלאי", is really useful in cases where you don't know exactly the word you're looking for.  The "search operators" button under tabular search expands the search to include prefixes and suffixes, for example you would get the Rashi I mentioned before if you search for ערבב with the G and F flags, or for ערב with the P and S flags.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer before I try it. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try them both, IY"H, later.

Comment: @Heshy Tzidkat Hatzadik is by R. Tzadok HaKohein of Lublin

Comment: @JoelK doesn't surprise me